# SwiftUI modal sheet dismisses itself after half a second

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have got a modal sheet, here is the code:

SettingsDashboardView:

```
   @State private var notificationsSettingsSheet = false

    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            self.notificationsSettingsSheet.toggle()
        }) {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 4) {
                    Label("Set Daily Reminders", systemImage: "alarm").foregroundColor(Color("TextColor"))
                        .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                

            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $notificationsSettingsSheet) {
            NotificationSettingsModal()
        } 
    }
```

NotificationSettingsModal:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ScrollView {
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                    
    
                    Text("Daily Reminders")
                        .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.top, headingTopPadding)
                    .padding(.horizontal, headingHorizontalPadding).foregroundColor(Color("TextColor"))
             
                    Spacer().frame(height: 164)

                }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                
                
                
                Spacer().frame(height: 64)
            }
        }.background(Color("BackgroundColor").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
    }
```

When I launch the app and open my sheet, in about 50% of cases sheet dismisses itself after about half a second. If I open sheet after that everything works fine. What can cause this problem?

Comment: Provided code snapshot works fine with Xcode 12.0 / iOS 14.

Comment: It turned out when I use .sheet on SettingsDashboardView which I embed into my main view it works bad as I described, but if I simply delete SettingsDashboardView file and paste it contents into my main view code, then everything works fine. Looks like a SwiftUI bug to me.

Answer (score 4):

*This will probably not solve the mentioned issue but can be useful for others.*

In most cases, this issue happens when the view gets redrawn due to a change in some variables. Be careful that it might be the parent view that have some variables changes.

The best way to debug this kind of behaviour is to use the technique describe [here, on Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-find-which-data-change-is-causing-a-swiftui-view-to-update). The idea is to identify what change caused a view to reload itself by printing `print(Self._printChanges())` inside the body property. Note that by doing it, you will temporarily need to add an explicit return.

Then, observer the console and it most cases you will be able to identify the issue and refactor your code.

In my experience (does not seem to be the case here) this often happens when using `@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode` in both the view and parent view. For some reasons this value changes in both views when presenting a sheet, causing the view to be redrawn and the sheet closed.

Comment: Better use `let _ = Self._printChanges()` to make it compile.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing the codes below while setting to NavigationView on my homeView this week, which caused my subView's sheet automatically dismissed the first time showing.

```
NavigationView {...}
// .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```